# How to create a colorful 3D volume plot based on RGBA data with Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, rgba

I want to create a 3D plot based on RGBA colors in Matplotlib (or any suitable alternative) similar to this one ([source](https://www.osapublishing.org/abstract.cfm?URI=ao-56-11-3024)):

[image: 3D "cloud-plot" with RGBA colors]

The basic idea is:

1. Have a data set with associated alpha values for R, G and B channels. That is, where R=0, the red channel is transparent, where R=1, the red channel is fully opaque.
2. Superpose the resulting RGB channels to get the image - just as a real-life image would be made by a projector, but in 3D.
   In 2D I could solve it with `pyplot.imshow`, but how can I do something equivalent in 3D?

As an example, here is some arbitrary data similar to mine:

```py
x = y = z = np.linspace(-3, 3, 200)
xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij')
gauss = np.exp(-(xx**2+yy**2+zz**2)/2)
red = np.sin((xx+yy) * np.pi)**2 * gauss
green = np.cos((yy+zz) * np.pi)**2 * gauss
blue = np.sin((xx+zz+0.25) * np.pi)**2 * gauss
```

If this was in 2D, I would do something along the lines of this, but ideally the colors would blend and wouldn't overlap each other. (I'm not sure how to do that in 2D without PIL, but it's not important for the core of this question.)

```py
# Create R, G and B channels and add the data as alpha value
red2, green2, blue2 = red[100], green[100], blue[100]
R = np.broadcast_to([1.0, 0, 0], (*red2.shape, 3))
G = np.broadcast_to([0, 1.0, 0], (*green2.shape, 3))
B = np.broadcast_to([0, 0, 1.0], (*blue2.shape, 3))
r = np.insert(R, 3, red2, axis=-1)
g = np.insert(G, 3, green2, axis=-1)
b = np.insert(B, 3, blue2, axis=-1)

# plot everything:
plt.imshow(r, aspect='auto', origin='lower', extent=(-3,3,-3,3))
plt.imshow(g, aspect='auto', origin='lower', extent=(-3,3,-3,3))
plt.imshow(b, aspect='auto', origin='lower', extent=(-3,3,-3,3))
plt.gca().set_facecolor('black')
plt.show()
```

[image: 2d psychedelic example]

But how could I do something similar in 3D?